# Request download in Windows Dockerfile fails with 'is not recognized'

Tags: windows, powershell, docker

I'm trying to build my own windows docker image. Within the dockerfile i want to download the current activemq zip file. I used several commands in order to accomplish this, but this always fails with an error message:

What I tried:

```
RUN powershell (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?filename=/activemq/5.15.0/apache-activemq-5.15.0-bin.zip&action=download', 'c:\temp\activemq.zip')

RUN powershell wget 'http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?filename=/activemq/5.15.0/apache-activemq-5.15.0-bin.zip&action=download' -OutFile 'c:\temp\activemq.zip'

RUN powershell Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?filename=/activemq/5.15.0/apache-activemq-5.15.0-bin.zip&action=download' -OutFile c:\temp\activemq.zip

RUN ['powershell', 'wget', 'http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?filename=/activemq/5.15.0/apache-activemq-5.15.0-bin.zip&action=download', '-OutFile', 'c:\temp\activemq.zip']

RUN powershell -command 'wget http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?filename=/activemq/5.15.0/apache-activemq-5.15.0-bin.zip&action=download -OutFile c:\temp\activemq.zip'
```

Results in

> 'action' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

```
RUN ["powershell", "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?filename=/activemq/5.15.0/apache-activemq-5.15.0-bin.zip&action=download -OutFile c:\temp\activemq.zip"]
```

results in

> '["powershell"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,    operable program or batch file.

I guess, I have to escape the `&` symbol. I tried the accent ` but this didn't work either. How can I download this file?

edit: 
the command and download works manually within a container.

Comment: can you provide the Dockerfile

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I figured it out. Just in case, if someone else faces this problem. I put double quotes around the whole command.
Following does work:

```
RUN powershell "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?filename=/activemq/5.15.0/apache-activemq-5.15.0-bin.zip&action=download', 'c:\temp\activemq.zip')"
```

Comment: I took this website as refernce: https://blog.jourdant.me/post/3-ways-to-download-files-with-powershell
Because of the con about the low download speed, I chose the WebClient. But thanks, there are some nice patterns which looks much cleaner than my current solution.